# Where is Copy As Python Snippet of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

When writing ArcPy code to use  with ArcGIS Desktop 10.x applications like ArcMap I will often run a Geoprocessing tool and then go to the **Geoprocessing | Results** window to right-click on that successful run to **Copy As Python Snippet** so that I can Paste that code into my script.

When I look for the same option in ArcGIS Pro there is no Results window to start from.

What is the equivalent workflow for ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After running a tool from the **Geoprocessing pane**, I found that I could right click on the successful run at the bottom (in green) and choose **Copy Python command**.

[image]

Alternatively, I could use **ANALYSIS | History** to open the **Project pane**'s **Geoprocessing History** and right-click the successful run there to choose **Copy Python command**.

[image]

Either workflow above places code like that below into the Paste buffer ready to be pasted into a script:

```
arcpy.management.CreateFishnet(r"C:\Temp\TestProj\TestProj.gdb\TestFishnet", "110 -35", "110 -20", 2, 1, None, None, "150 -20", "NO_LABELS", "DEFAULT", "POLYGON")
```